# Failled to partition error during installation

Tags: dual-boot

I have Thinkpad T61 with 2 G RAM & 500 GM HD, partitioned to 3 volume. one volume created while setting up windows 7 home version reserved for recovery and then C drive where the windows 7 installed. I used Wubi (CD ROM) to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Os type 32bit), after first reboot Ubuntu start to install and suddenly an error pops up as below and attached picture:

---

Failed to partition the selected disk (as superuser)

---

this probably happened because there are too many (primary) 
partitions in the partition table

---

I have only 1 primary partition in my HD, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your picture failed to post as of this moment, but I assume Windows must have written some form write-protection to prevent any other Operating Systems from being installed, otherwise, it may be that the options you chose for installation were off. If you do not mind posting those, that would be helpful.
I've yet to see a hard drive that has meet a partition limit, so I assume it's either an option set by Windows, however unlikely, or one of your installation options needs to be tweaked.

I recommend trying it this way; on the page where you partition your drive:

- Choose the disk drive you wish to install it on, that being the larger disk of the ones listed -- most likely listed as sda.
- Create a new partition from the free space used with Windows, though this could be risky and will require you to verify drive C:\ upon the next Windows boot, and set its partitioning to consist of either NTFS (compatible with Windows) or EXT4 (Not accessible from within Windows)
- Make sure to set that as the root directory that ubuntu will be install to.
- At the bottom, it asks for the drive where the bootloader is installed and offers a drop-down list. This needs to be the sda drive from before.

From there, you shouldn't need to do much else, so start the installation and watch for errors.

If you want your windows bootloader back instead of grub2, run a program called EasyBCD (the Non-Commercial Version), found here:
https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

Comment: It seems that WuBi does not work with Ubuntu 14.10 - I found another question regarding this issue. Thanks for assistance - appreciated.